# How can I Decrypt P7S Using C#

Tags: encryption, openssl

I Have Some P7M And P7S Files got from My Client.

I want o Extract Attachments from the Corresponding Files

I am able to decrypt P7M And Extracted Attachments from that eml Files using OpenSSL
but when it come to the case of P7S the decryption method is not working

Is there any one can help to the correct way of decryption format of Openssl

Comment: Please indicate what you did using OpenSSL and share your C# code by hitting [edit].

Comment: ['p7s' is standardly used for a CMS-formerly-PKCS7 detached signature that forms part of a clearsigned S/MIME message.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551#section-3.5.3) Such a signature cannot be decrypted because it is not encrypted. It _can_ be _verified_ if the associated data is available. Some people might also use it for a CMS/PKCS7 signature with embedded data, although standardly that should be 'p7m'. What exactly do you have and what are you trying to do? Note that _running_ programs rather than programming is out of scope for SO and might belong an a different Stack.